# How manipulate transposed matrix on HDF5 Fortran

Tags: fortran, hdf5

I am currently working on a code to solve a linear system of linear equations with Scalapack on Fortran. I am using HDF5 to pass the data, but I am having trouble because the answers do not match when I do a distributed run. It appears that the entire matrix is a transposed matrix and the rows and columns of the blocks are reversed. Naturally, the matrix itself is also transposed.
Is there a way to handle the transposed matrix in the HDF5 read with the least performance hit?
Is there?

Comment: Can you show some details? First you say that the answers differ but then you spesk about performance. Performance in which sense? How much do the results differ? What exactly ate you doing with the matrix? I have no idea what *"It appears that the entire matrix is a transposed matrix and the rows and columns of the blocks are reversed. Naturally, the matrix itself is also transposed."* means.  It is best to illustrate what you are doing with some code.

Comment: Fortran matrix (i.e. 2D array) indexing is column major. If your data come from a langage that is row major, and depending how you are reading them, this could explain what are you are observing.

Comment: The main program is built in Python and receives data from Python in HDF5 with h5py; a subprogram to be built in Fortran receives two matrices A and B. The Fortran subprogram uses Scalapack to solve the simultaneous equations with AX=B and X in HDF5 and returns X to HDF5.